# Sizing the SQL Agent Job Activity Monitor screen

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Does anyone know how to reset the initial (default) window size that is used when opening the SQL server Agent Job Activity Monitor screen?
When opening the Job Activity Monitor we always need to drag the window open to see the relevant columns. 
Can this not be set/saved to always open at the width that I want?

Comment: No. When all the Agent functionality makes it over to Azure Data Studio, it's more likely you'll get what you want there, since it's both open source and a lot of the configuration options for various screens and other UI elements are controlled by simple JSON prefs as opposed to hard-coded in MVC or WinForms code...

Comment: Thanks Aaron...so I'll just have to wait and hope.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done.

This is the additional 16 characters required to post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but any evidence or reason for saying "it can't be done".

Comment: My reason is that it isn't a feature available and never has been. I'm not sure how you expect one to prove the absence of a feature from a product.

Comment: Thanks LowlyDBA...appreciate getting your explanation and was hoping that someone had perhaps worked out how to get behind the published features and get this to work. Looks to me as if it's hardcoded and that's just the way it is. Looks as if Aaron agrees with you and I.